# Why does my network stop with TypeError on the second batch?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

My network starts to learn and looks okay on the first batch and then suddenly stops with TypeError on the second batch only! Why was it okay on the first batch then? Or why did it break after the first? Stupefying error... Here are the details:

I have built a CNN that is trying to predict 124 features for each image. The images are of size **61 x 72** pixels and the output vector of numbers are of size **124 x 1**.
The images are floating point matrices with numbers between **1** and **-1**.
The information I'm trying to predict is in a CSV file, with each line describing an image. When I load the data for the training process I process each line and reshape them, also get the pictures the network is learning.
When I run my program, I get the following error ***on the second batch***, however:

> "TypeError: Fetch argument 2.7674865e+09 has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a float32 into a Tensor or Operation.)"

Can you please help pinpoint what the problem is? Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data_in=np.loadtxt(open("images.csv"), delimiter=',',dtype=np.float32);
data_out=np.loadtxt(open("outputmix-124.csv"), 
          delimiter=',',dtype=np.float32);

x_train = data_in[0:6000, :]
x_test = data_in[6000:10000,:]
y_train = data_out[0:6000, :]
y_test = data_out[6000:10000, :]

batch=600
epochs=10

n = x_test.shape[1] #4392
m = x_train.shape[0] #6000
d = y_test.shape[1]  #124
l = y_test.shape[0]     #4000

trainX= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch, n], name="X")
trainY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch, d])

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def maxpool2d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], 
           padding='SAME')


def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_c1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
               'W_c2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([18 * 16 * 64, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, d]))}

    biases = {'b_c1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
              'b_c2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([d]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1,61,72, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_c1']) + biases['b_c1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_c2']) + biases['b_c2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 18 * 16 * 64])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    cost =tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(prediction-trainY,2))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for i in (np.linspace(0,m - batch, m / batch, dtype=np.int32)):
                x = x_train[i:i + batch, :]
                y = y_train[i:i + batch, :]
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={trainX: x, trainY: y})
                cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={trainX: x, trainY: y})
                print("Epoch=", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "loss=", " 
                      {:.9f}".format(cost))
                epoch_loss += cost

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', epochs, 'loss:', 
                 epoch_loss)

train_neural_network(trainX)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly typical mistake. The problem is with the variable ***cost***. First you assign the loss calculation tensor to it in the second line of the function `train_neural_network()`:

```
cost =tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(prediction-trainY,2))
```

Then when you run the training and the cost calculation, you do this, and this is where it gets messed up:

```
cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={trainX: x, trainY: y})
```

because you assign the *value of the loss* to ***cost***, which is now a simple floating point number, instead of a Tensor. The next time around `sess.run()` gets a floating point number instead of a tensor as a first argument, and the error above is printed.

Use something like ***cost_val*** for storing the value of the loss and leave ***cost*** to store the reference to the tensor. You of course need to update the lines that print the value as well, so these three lines I've changed:

```
cost_val = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={trainX: x, trainY: y})
print("Epoch=", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "loss=", " {:.9f}".format(cost_val))
epoch_loss += cost_val
```

I'm posting the full revised version here (tested code; note I've generated test data instead of loading; this is a loadable and testable example for anyone but you need to change it back to load your actual data):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

keep_rate = 0.8

#data_in=np.loadtxt(open("images.csv"), delimiter=',',dtype=np.float32);
#data_out=np.loadtxt(open("outputmix-124.csv"), 
#          delimiter=',',dtype=np.float32);

data_in = np.random.normal( size = ( 10000, 4392 ) )
data_out = np.random.normal( size = ( 10000, 124 ) )

x_train = data_in[0:6000, :]
x_test = data_in[6000:10000,:]
y_train = data_out[0:6000, :]
y_test = data_out[6000:10000, :]

batch=600
epochs=10

n = x_test.shape[1] #4392
m = x_train.shape[0] #6000
d = y_test.shape[1]  #124
l = y_test.shape[0]     #4000

trainX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch, n], name="X")
trainY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch, d])

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def maxpool2d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], 
           padding='SAME')


def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_c1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
               'W_c2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([18 * 16 * 64, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, d]))}

    biases = {'b_c1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
              'b_c2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([d]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1,61,72, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_c1']) + biases['b_c1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_c2']) + biases['b_c2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 18 * 16 * 64])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = convolutional_neural_network(x)
    cost =tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(prediction-trainY,2))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for i in (np.linspace(0,m - batch, m / batch, dtype=np.int32)):
                x = x_train[i:i + batch, :]
                y = y_train[i:i + batch, :]
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={trainX: x, trainY: y})
                cost_val = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={trainX: x, trainY: y})
                print("Epoch=", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "loss=", " {:.9f}".format(cost_val))
                epoch_loss += cost_val

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', epochs, 'loss:', 
                 epoch_loss)

train_neural_network(trainX)
```

Comment: @sagitrabilse: did the answer above work for you? if yes, can you please accept the answer?